# php вывод имен из массива

Tags: php, массивы, вывод

Есть переменная актеров, там их несколько
Вот так я их вывожу:

```
<?php $prsns_titles = []; ?>

<?php $mdls = $this->_models ?>
<?php $role = current($mdls)->_elements ?>
<!-- <?php var_dump("<pre>", current($role)->number, "</pre>") ?> -->

<?php $prsns =  current($mdls)->_persons?>
<?php var_dump("<pre>", $prsns, "</pre>")  ?>
```

Получаю вот это (это кусочек):

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#239 (19) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["eid"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(45) "Александр Бородинский"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(23) "aleksandr-borodinsky"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(48) "images/persons/thumbs/AleksandrVoskresenskiy.jpg"
    ["icon"]=>
    string(47) "images/persons/icons/AleksandrVoskresenskiy.jpg"
    ["images"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["info"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(312) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#240 (19) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["eid"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(35) "Александр Анисипов"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(19) "aleksandr-anisipov"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(44) "images/persons/thumbs/AleksandrAnisipov.jpg"
    ["icon"]=>
    string(43) "images/persons/icons/AleksandrAnisipov.jpg"
    ["images"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["info"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(471) "
```

Но мне нужно вывести только их имена все
Я не совсем понимаю как мне их все положить в переменную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

foreach ($prsns as $person) {
    echo $person->title;
}


?>
```

---

Другой вариант:

```
echo implode(',', array_column($prsns, 'title'));
```

выведет все имена через запятую

Comment: Спасибо! Спаботало